# May I use many wysiwyg jquery selectors with textareas?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, wildcard, wysihtml5

I'm using [bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails](https://github.com/Nerian/bootstrap-wysihtml5-rails) in my rails app, all is working well until I attempt to use a wildcard selector.

For example:

***Javascript***

```
$('[id*=some-textarea]').wysihtml5();
```

***HTML***

```
<textarea id="some-textarea1" placeholder="Enter text ..."></textarea>
<textarea id="some-textarea2" placeholder="Enter text ..."></textarea>
```

Does not work on Chrome Version 22.0.1229.94, console is saying "Uncaught Error: NOT_FOUND_ERR: DOM Exception 8"

Safari show's the wysiwyg controls on some-textarea1 only.

When I'm explicit, they work fine

```
$('#some-textarea1').wysihtml5();
$('#some-textarea2').wysihtml5();
```

But the number of textarea's on my rails form are dynamic, so I'd really like to use a wildcard, if at all possible?

Is this an issue with wysiwyg.js?  As a simple css background change works...

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/8PBwA/3/

Comment: Try encasing your selector in Double-Quotes.. Check if that helps

Comment: @Sushanth-- afraid not :( http://jsfiddle.net/8PBwA/5/

Comment: check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/XEWC8/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to go out on a limb here (from a quick look at the plugin source) and say that this JS plugin does not support a collection as an argument.

You can use a `for` loop.

```
$('[id*=some-textarea]').each(function() {
     $(this).wysihtml5();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try encasing your selector in Double-Quotes.. Check if that helps

```
$('[id*="some-textarea"]').wysihtml5();
```

Also you can try assigning a **single class** to all those text areas..

```
<textarea id="some-textarea1" class="w5text" placeholder="Enter text ..."></textarea>
<textarea id="some-textarea2" class="w5text" placeholder="Enter text ..."></textarea>

$('.w5text').wysihtml5();
```

OR

```
var count = 30;

for(var i = ;i<= count ; i++){
   $('#some-textarea'+ count).wysihtml5();
}
```

Comment: yeah I've tried both of those. http://jsfiddle.net/8PBwA/6/  No luck :(  I've also tried start with & end with selectors

Comment: If you know the number of text boxes you have on page .. You can try running a for loop..